# Python 3.5 / Importing values from another script /

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have some problem with importing variables from another script (Python 3.5, IDE Spyder).
Both scripts in the same folder.

```
First.py
a = "1"
b = 2

Second.py
from First import a,b
print(a,b)
```

I get error: "ImportError: cannot import name 'a'"

If i use:

```
Second.py
import First
print(First.a)
```

I get: "module 'First' has no attribute 'a'" (expected result)

and last:

```
Second.py
from First import *
print(a)
```

I get: "name 'a' is not defined"

All works fine with functions, but here https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/modules.html it says that I can use importing with variables.

What is wrong?

Comment: Did you save `First.py` before running `Second.py`?

Comment: You're right. Thanks man.